# Database-driven website with (almost) no programming

Tags: database, web-applications

Is there any reasonably attractive approach to building a basic database-driven website with only very light/simple programming (i.e., without using PHP, Python, Ruby, .NET, etc.)? I was imagining some trivial declarative language for database lookup that gets processed server-side. Something that anyone with HTML and SQL knowledge can figure out in a day or two.

I heard of ColdFusion but it seems to be on a downward spiral.

I read about [non-programmer friendly CMS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18239/which-cms-can-i-use-to-build-a-website-without-programming-knowledge), but I need to be able to write my own SQL queries, and I doubt CMS allows that. (In addition, I only have a couple of web pages of content, so CMS is probably an overkill.)

Does it mean as long as the website needs to talk to a database, a developer must be involved in making it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not tied to a specific RDBMS, I'd recommend APEX. It

- is part of the Oracle database
- requires no external tools (your Browser is the IDE)
- allows quick development of database-driven applications (Reports, Master/Detail, CRUD functionality)

You can [try it online](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html)  (free registration required).

Comment: Interesting. I also found this [discussion of APEX](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2201321) that adds some clarity about its pros and cons.